# Angularjs 100 pages with same layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating an angularjs app. The app has two templates, but 100 pages that use the templates.

I don't want to have 100 static template files, I really only want two template files and the content changes dynamically.

What is the best practice to do this in angularjs?

Currently I have something similar to this, but I want to remove the content from the controller as once I've added 100 pages, it'll be hard to main and not easily readable.

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
        $scope.data = [
            {
                'name': 'test',
                'data': 'test'
            },
            {
                'name': 'test',
                'data': 'test'
            },
            {
                'name': 'test',
                'data': 'test'
            },
            {
                'name': 'test',
                'data': 'test'
            },
            {
                'name': 'test',
                'data': 'test'
            }
        ];
    });
```

Comment: From your example you want to use 2 templates. So where is a problem to change the content?

Comment: @MaximShoustin I would just have different data sets for each template. I'm looking for an alternate way to store the data. e.g json files or sqllite.

Comment: you need Directives. Nothing else.

Comment: @HarishR I'm not sure you've understood the question.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) modules to template your files. (ngRoute is for simpler applications while ui-router let's you do more advanced things like nested routes)

With both of these, you can define a main template file and then have a different controller/data for each page.

### Quick Example of ngRoute

You would include the ng-route file in your project and then inject it into your application. Then you would use `$routeProvider` to define your pages.

#### HTML

Now you have a template file and all of your views will be injected into the `<div ng-view></div>` area.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- head stuff here -->
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="main">

        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS needed for this.

#### JS

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

    // configure our routes
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page with specific controller
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            });
    });
```

Now `pages/home.html` will be injected into the main template when you visit the home page in your browser. The controller for each route would be where you get the data and pass it to that template file using `$scope`.

### Further Reading

- [Single Page Apps with AngularJS Routing and Templating](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)
- [AngularJS Routing Using UI-Router](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

*Full Disclosure:* I wrote these two articles.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Its not the routing I'm having problems with. its more of a question of organising my data for each page to use. e.g Using json or storing the data in an sqllite database. Thanks

Comment: Got it. When storing data in your database, a good way to organize that is to create a server-side API (probably node/express) to access your database and return JSON data. Then you would use Angular services (injected into your Angular controllers) to access that API. Use `$http` and bind the results to the variables you need that will be passed to the view.